# Can't install vowpalwabbit via pip in Windows

Tags: python, pip, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install vowpalwabbit by using pip in Windows.

My python version is 3.7. As I am new in using vowpalwabbit, it is possible that I forget to configure some external dependencies. Therefore, can you please explain every single the step to make it work. I got the following error when I run the following:

`pip install vowpalwabbit`

````
raise Exception('Pre-built vw/python library for Windows is not supported for this python version')
Exception: Pre-built vw/python library for Windows is not supported for this python version```
----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\I516\Documents\Newsfeed\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\I336\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3tgy0rvf\\vowpalw
abbit\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\I336\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-record-o5qdntld\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\I336\Documents\Newsfeed\venv\include\site\python3.7\vowp
alwabbit" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\I336\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3tgy0rvf\vowpalwabbit\```
````

Comment: Have you seen [this Dependencies page](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Dependencies#windows) from the project?

Comment: @umbe1987 Yes, I've seen them. I have installed MS Visual Studio 2019. But I didn't understand what is vcpkg is? I am suspecting with the python version.

Comment: After a quick reading of these two issues on the very github page of the project ([1](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1176) and [2](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1342)) it seems your best bet on windows is using Python 3.5.... maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Vowpalwabbit using pip on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306861/cant-install-vowpalwabbit-using-pip-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new version of vowpalwabbit (8.7.0) was released to PyPI last week. In addition, binary wheels for 64-bit Python 3.6/3.7 are available for Windows.

If you're using the 64-bit version of Python (or can switch to using it):

```sh
pip install vowpalwabbit
```

should work properly without any additional dependencies